# Comparing incrementing filenames in Python and check which one is missing

Tags: python, list

I'm iterating through a folder with files and adding each of the file's path to a list. The folder contains files with incrementing file names, such as `00-0.txt, 00-1.txt, 00-2.txt, 01-0.txt, 01-1.txt, 01-2.txt` and so on.

The number of files is not fixed and always varies. Also, sometimes a file could be missing. This means that I will sometimes get this list instead:
`00-0.txt, 00-1.txt, 01-0.txt, 01-1.txt, 01-2.txt.`

However, in my final list, I should always have groups of 9 (so 00-0, 00-1, 00-2 and so on until 00-8 is one group). If a file is missing, then I will append 'is missing' string text in the new list instead.

What I was thinking to do is the following:

- Get the last character of the filename (for ex. '3')
- Check if it's value is the same as the previous index + 1.
- If it's not, then append 'it's missing' string
- If it's the same, then append the file name

In **pseudo-code** (please don't mind the syntax errors, I'm mainly looking for high level advice), it would be something like this:

```
empty_list = []
list_with_paths = glob.glob("/path/to/dir*.txt")

for index, item in enumerate(list_with_paths):
    basename = os.path.basename(item)
    filename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]

    if index == 0 and int(filename[-1]) != 0:
        empty_list.append('is missing')
    elif filename[-1] != empty_list[index - 1] + 1:
        empty_list.append('is missing')
    else:
        empty_list.append(filename)
```

I'm sure there is a more optimal solution in order to achieve this.

Comment: How many groups are there supposed to be? It would seem easier to simply generate the *expected* names, then check if each one exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the set of actual paths, just iterate over the *expected* paths until you have accounted for all of the actual paths.

```
from itertools import count

list_with_paths = set(glob.glob("/path/to/dir/*.txt"))

groups = count()

results = []
for g in groups:
    if not list_with_paths:
        break
    for i in range(0,9):
        expected = "{:02}-{}.txt".format(g, i)
        if "/path/to/dir/" + expected in list_with_paths:
            list_with_paths.remove(expected)
        else:
            expected = "is missing"
        results.append(expected)
```

Comment: It does, which is to account for the uncertainly about how many groups there should be. Check that `"/path/to/dir/" + expected` generates a correct path string; otherwise, we'll never actually deplete the set of paths, and the set will never be empty. (Also, note that I just added a `/` between `dir` and `*.txt` in the glob; I don't know if that's relevant.)